# How to include the list items in tool bar menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, toolbar

I have installed the tool bar on ios phone gap. Now I want to add list of item under "More" tool bar. How can I include list on click of "More" tool bar. So on click of "More" the list should popup.

My tool bar event code is as follows,

```
var tabBar = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/iOSTabBar");
tabBar.init();
tabBar.create({selectedImageTintColorRgba: "255,40,0,255"});
tabBar.createItem("More", "More", "tabButton:More", {
onSelect: function() {
     // Here I want to add the list
 }
});
tabBar.createItem("About us", "About us", "/www/pixeden-tab-bar-icons-ios-7/line__0000s_0126_info.png", {
onSelect: function() {
      aboutus();
  }
 })

 tabBar.show();
  tabBar.showItems("About us", "More");
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() { tabBar.resize() }, false);
```

I need to include the list as follows,

```
<ul>  
   <li class="newsfeed"><a href="#" title="Home">News Feed</a></li>  
   <li class="profile"><a href="#" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>  
   <li class="setting"><a href="#" title="Setting">Setting</a></li>  
   <li class="logout"><a href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>  
   <li class="report"><a href="#" title="Report">Report Bug</a></li>  
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Why can you not add 'about us' in the html?

Comment: I will do that. But How can I add the list items under more tab

Comment: Can you add `about us` as an `li` element? Then it will be easier.

Comment: If I add about us as an li element, How can I display entire list. give me some suggestions How can I display my menu items

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

JavaScript version: - This will work on a phone

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UkC2r/1/)

[Final version](http://jsfiddle.net/UkC2r/5/)

HTML:

```
<ul>  
   <li class="newsfeed"><a href="#" title="Home">News Feed</a></li>  
   <li class="profile"><a href="#" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>  
   <li class="setting"><a href="#" title="Setting">Setting</a></li>  
   <li class="logout"><a href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>  
   <li class="report"><a href="#" title="Report">Report Bug</a></li>
   <li class="about"><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href='#'>Something</a></li>
           <li><a href='#'>Something else</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var about = document.getElementsByClassName("about")[0];

about.onclick = function()
{
    if (this.className == "about clicked")
    {
        this.className = "about";
    }else{
        this.className = "about clicked";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
ul li{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

ul li ul{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}


ul li.clicked ul {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    left:-45px;
}

ul li.clicked ul li{
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: but the UI doesn't look good right? Is can't it possible on click of more button the list should displaying

Comment: Updated @user3300593 Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: I will do the UI part. can you please update how does on click works here in your example

Comment: What do you mean how does it work? When the user clicks it, it will add a class that the css recognizes and makes the list items visible. When clicked again, it will disappear. @user3300593

Comment: I need that on click of any button button in header or footer then I need to show the list of menu. Just like how panel works. I need that as a side menu or toll bar menu item

Comment: So you want this to work for all items that have a list? @user3300593 I'm confused as to what you mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51894/discussion-between-beatalex-and-user3300593)

Comment: Here is multiple elements having a list @user3300593 http://jsfiddle.net/UkC2r/2/

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to explain it properly. I need just like panel as there in the following link http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/

Comment: What come out at the side of the page? @user3300593

Comment: I will attach the screen shot then you will understand
I have attached the screen shot
I need the list to be on click of menu button or on clcik of more button they should display as a side menu
I hope now you can understand my problem

Comment: In the screen shot assume that business, numbers, money people are the list of items instead of news feed, profile e.t.c

Comment: Something like this? @user3300593 http://jsfiddle.net/UkC2r/3/  (click on about us)

Comment: Yes will that ad let you know

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand?

Comment: I need the same which you modified. So i will try it in my application. Thank you

Comment: yes. I will try in my application and accept your answer

Comment: Yes it is working. But finally can you show me the event on click of "some thing" link. just a dialog box or showing an alert